# Looking for a text editor with navigation/categorization

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-editors

I've been looking for a text editor that automatically (or at least makes it easy to-) make some sort of navigation. Adobe Reader has this functionality with its bookmark system:

[image]

Right now, though, I'm using Word 2007. For each section, I go Insert > Bookmark, highlight the text, copy/paste the text as the link information, and it appears at the top of the document. I've made a macro to add bookmarks easier, but it's still pretty awful, and the bookmarks are still at the top of the page (rather than in the sidebar, where it's always accessible)

Honestly, I would just prefer to write it in a PDF like in that screenshot. But any text editor with this type of functionality would work. It just needs basic formatting options, bold/font size, underline, images, maybe tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try LibreOffice. It has a [navigator panel](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Navigator) that can be docked to the side of the window. Use `F5` to show/hide the panel.

Instead of bookmarks, format your targets as headings. A double- or triple-click will select the word or line, then you choose e.g. `Heading 1` from the format toolbar. Pretty easy, but not automatic. You can format the heading 1 style to match your remaining text or not--your choice. Use F11 to open the Styles dialog.

The headings will show up in the navigator panel and you can move to the section by double-clicking in the panel.

You can choose to save the file as plain text, and even make that the default, but then you would lose the style information.

Comment: Thank you, that navigation panel is exactly what I was looking for. Although, I really wish there were a plugin for Office 07. Now I have to get used to this one, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

### Folding

Text editors such as vim have configurable [text-folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding_editor), which can be used to collapse the text to an outline view for quick navigation between sections.

### Mark-up

You could use this in conjunction with [plain-text markup](https://superuser.com/posts/209897/edit) such as [multi-markdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) to provide headings, bold, tables etc.